# How to change the DNS of an Android device programatically with a VPN?

Tags: java, android, networking, dns, vpn

I'm making a DNS changer app to learn some beginner stuff, and I can't figure out a way to change the device DNS server programmatically. I tried to search in android documentation and Googling, but I didn't found anything.

I thought of creating a local VPN that will use the chosen DNS, but I still don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the source code for this application

https://github.com/iTXTech/Daedalus

Take a look at the classes he calls in [DaedalusVpnService.java](https://github.com/iTXTech/Daedalus/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/itxtech/daedalus/service/DaedalusVpnService.java)

```
Daedalus.initRuleResolver();
DNSServerHelper.buildPortCache();
```